# How do I add a css/jQuery transition effect when a user touches the screen on mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

Bust out your phone and go to this website: http://www.mcbsfarm.com/

If you scroll down and just touch any of the four boxes they turn from gray to blue.

It's not merely an element:hover answer. Really take a look at how those boxes activate, especially when scrolling down. Long-pressing the boxes activates the color change without sending the user to the links behind them. How can I do this with CSS or jQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In CSS it is known as: `hover` and the touch screen mobile, would handle it as a touch not focus.

You can try this:

```
element:hover { // on hover
  background-color: blue;
}
```

In jQuery it would be an event as:

```
$('selector').hover(function () { // on hover!!
  $(this).css('background-color', 'blue'); // change the css
}
```

Using the API, you can detect some of the changes; events, and then run the code depending on the event and the element. You can stylize the element in CSS, as CSS is just meant for styling purposes, but in jQuery you can alter the CSS properties of other elements as well as you can execute more functions too, such as ajax requests.

You really need to learn the APIs of CSS and jQuery before moving forward!

jQuery: http://www.jquery.com

CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your input, however it is not purely an element:hover effect. It's activated by touch only, while a user scrolls etc, without actually activating the links behind them.

Comment: Yes, touch handles hover effects that way. I have tried the link you provided and I found that the code for this style was `:hover` in the inspector. Hover is when a user mouse over the element...

Comment: Please look at this on mobile though and as your scrolling down touch the boxes. It's different. 

I'm an advanced front-end programmer and know what hover affects are 0_0. After spending about an hour looking through chrome dev tools and searching stack + google on what type of transition this is. I can only guess it's CSS3 or a jQuery function because it's activated by touch only without actually activating the links behind the elements. A :hover effect alone cannot do this.

Comment: Might have found it...looks like there is a `tapHold` function in jQuery: http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/

Answer (score -1):

Whoo I got it!!

You have to use the jQuery tapHold function. Here's a great example from Rich Adams on GitHub:
https://github.com/richadams/jquery-taphold

Here's the way I did it on my code, live example on my site: http://straubcreativeco.nationbuilder.com/web_development

```
    $("#icon-block").bind("taphold", function()
{
    $(this).css('background', '#cd763a');
});
```

ezpz :D